How do I create a scroll which is similar to this?
I am trying to create a similar scroll like this.
Now I have created a structure in reactjs but I am not able to figure the left side scroll when right side is sticky without using any library.


.project-section {
  height: 400vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightcoral; 
}

.project-heading {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: var(--font-size-heading);
}

.project-heading-text {
  font-family: Campton-Font-Bold;
  font-size: var(--font-size-heading);
}

.project-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.project-container-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center; /* or space-around */
  align-items: center; /* Ensure this has a value, like 'center' */
  height: 300vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.project-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.project-container-images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.project-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<section class="project-section" style="top: 0px;"><div class="project-heading"><span class="project-heading-text">Projects</span></div><div class="project-header"><div class="project-container-text"><span class="project-text">Text 1</span><span class="project-text">Text 2</span><span class="project-text">Text 3</span></div><div class="project-container-images" style="position: initial; top: 0px;"><span class="project-image">image1</span></div></div></section>



Functionality:

The Project headline should stick on top.
The Right side should also stick on top.
The Left side should be able to scroll and the text 1 and text 2 and text 3 should appear one by one while rest of the part should be sticky.

Bonus Question: As given in the link above, for reference, please let me know how to work on the image stack scrolling?
PS: cannot provide the github repo as it is a private project.
Note: I am using it in a react.js project.

Why not use library that is already solved all these issues?

I wanted to learn more about the internal process, and building it from scratch would help me improve my css and js.

The main trick is to use container to set height for the viewport and make right side sticky, while left should be scrollable by y-axis from container css. So, you basically scroll the container, not the left side only, but right part remains sticky

.project-section: Set the height to 100vh so that it takes the full
height of the viewport and ensures that the .project-header has a
fixed height.
.project-header: Container for both the left and
right sections. Set full height (100%) and overflow: hidden to prevent scrolling.
.project-container-text: overflow-y: auto to enable
independent scrolling. The height is set to 100% of its parent
container so it doesn’t extend beyond it.
.project-container-images: The sticky section on the right has
position: sticky and top: 0 to keep it fixed as the viewport
scrolls.

NOTE: Please run snippet in a full window to see the correct result.


.project-section {
  height: 100vh; /* Set this to viewport height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.project-heading {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: var(--font-size-heading);
  padding: 10px;
}

.project-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Full height to match the viewport */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow on the main container */
}

.project-container-text {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; /* Full height of the container */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Make it scrollable */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.project-text {
  height: 100vh; /* Example height for each text block */
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.project-container-images {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; /* Full height to match the viewport */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Sticks the element to the top */
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.project-image {
  height: 100vh; /* Example height for each image block */
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<section class="project-section">
  <div class="project-heading">
    <span class="project-heading-text">Projects</span>
  </div>
  <div class="project-header">
    <div class="project-container-text">
      <div class="project-text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="project-text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="project-text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-container-images">
      <div class="project-image">Image 1</div>
      <div class="project-image">Image 2</div>
      <div class="project-image">Image 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




But, perhaps, some libraries are out there that also allow parallax effect out of the box for such functionality and much more, tbh. I would rather look for one before jumping into DIY project. Was just curious to figure out how this actually works.

Thank you for your help. Pavlo, the code works just as intended.
I will definitely check into libraries, such as GSAP. Personally, I doubt that if I utilize a library while creating my portfolio, it will be considered as if I am simply implementing libraries rather than using my own talents.
